# email validation using jquery in zend framework 2

Tags: jquery, validation, email, zend-framework2

view file:

```
    email: {
          required: true,
                    email: true,
                     remote: {
                        url: 'deforay/admin/login/emailcheck',
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: {
                          mail: function(){ return $("#email").val(); }
                        }
                    }
    }

messages:
{
email: {
                    required: "Please provide a email-id",
                    email: "Please provide a valid email-id",
                    remote: "Mail-id already exist"
}
}
```

controller:

```
public function emailcheckAction() {

    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        $param = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
        $service = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('CompanyService');
        $result = $service->getEmail($param['mail']);
    }

    if ($result) {
        $value = false; //'Email already exists';
    } else {
        $value = true;
    }

    $email = $this->getResponse()->setContent(Json::encode(array('response' => $value)));
    return $email;
}
```

}

dbtable:

```
public function getEmail($param) {
        $dbadapter = $this->adapter;
        $sql = new Sql($dbadapter);
        $select = $sql->select();
        $select->columns(array('email'));
        $select->from('company');
        $select->where(array('email' => $param));

        $selectString = $sql->getSqlStringForSqlObject($select);
        $results = $dbadapter->query($selectString, $dbadapter::QUERY_MODE_EXECUTE);
        if (count($results) > 0) {
            $results = $results->current()->getArrayCopy();
            $response['status'] = 'exist';
            $response['email'] = array('email' => $results['email']);
        }
        if ($response) {
            return $response;
        }
    }
```

where is the problem, while i check using debug, i am getting response in controller but not getting correct answer ("Mail-id already exist" is not showing, if i type the existing mail id)

Comment: Its pretty hard to say since you haven't provided what getEmail method  of Company service does, does it return null if the email isn't found? What do you mean correct answer is it always true or always false Or just inconsistent. Also this is awesome and you should use it instead https://github.com/bramstroker/zf2-form

Comment: i added the details now